# Rendering CGAL::Triangulation_3 Glitches on edges

Tags: c++, rendering, metal, cgal, triangulation

How I would have to proceed to render a Delaunay 3D triangulation ?
I'm getting glitches in the edges... and its normal given that there are three facets colliding there, so three values of normals around the edge.
I need a triangulation because I'm working in a cristal look with transparency and inner facets so convex hull is not enough.

My actual attempt is sort the triangles in camera axis:

1. far half of the convex hull triangles
2. not convex hull triangles sorted in camera axis.
3. near half of the convex hull triangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort facets in camera axis to avoid glitches on edges works